# Application restarting after installing from SDCard and putting it on Background

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-install-apk

I've created a sample application (just a textview, nothing else), and I noticed a bug.
After installing it from the SDCard, it displays the "Application installed" screen, with the done and open buttons.

If I click the open button, a strange thing occurs:
Whenever I put the application in background and reopen it from the application icon, it doesn't reopen it, it creates a new instance.
I can confirm that it is creating a new instance, because after putting it on background and reopening a few times, when I click the back button, it opens the previous instance, instead of returning to the home screen.

Now the strange thing is that it only happens after installing from the SDCard and clicking on the open button.
If I click the done button (or installing via ADB) and open the application via icon, it doesn't happen.
Also, if I click the open button (and the bug occurs), after the application is ended for the first time, the bug doesn't occurs anymore.

I've tested it in different devices and in different Android versions (GB, HC and ICS), and the bug is reproducing in them all.

Does someone know if this is an known issue from Android and if so, does someone have an official reference that I can refer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure the problem isn't in the app? do you have the source code?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure. I haven't changed a single line from the template when you create the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it is a nasty, well-known Android bug that has been around since the very beginning. See the following:

[Android issue 26658](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26658)

[Android issue 2373](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373)

[Android app acts differently installed from adb vs sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390019/android-app-acts-differently-installed-from-adb-vs-sdcard/14465327#14465327)